# Specify TextButton padding in skin json file?

Tags: libgdx

I have a typical skin json file, like the sample one here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json

is it possible to specify "inner" padding for text buttons (the space around the text to the edge of the button) in the skin file - or can we only do that programatically at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: do not know if this is what you want or you can help, once replied something like, with a simple example of how you could do hope you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738239/libgdx-json-textbutton-how-to-align-label/26748766#26748766 is not exactly the same but it might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons in scene2d use the background drawable to determine padding. To the best of my knowledge, the only three reliable ways to set the padding of a Button are

1. Use a 9 patch drawable for the background drawable. The 9 patch defines its own padding.
2. Programatically modify any Drawable to have padding by using its `setTopHeight()`, `setLeftWidth()`, etc. methods. Then apply this Drawable as the Button's background programatically.
3. **Edit:** As of LibGDX 1.7.2, this is now possible to do by specifying a TextureRegionDrawable in the JSON file. Use a TextureRegionDrawable as the background of the button and define its padding like this:

   `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable: {
       paddedWhite: { region: white, leftWidth: 5, rightWidth: 5, topHeight: 4, bottomHeight: 4 }
   }`

Note that if you simply use `button.pad(...)`, your padding settings will be cancelled the moment the button is pressed the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Along with your .json file, you should also have a .atlas file
in your .atlas file, you define your button

in your .atlas file:

```
Button.png
size: 70,10
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
Button1
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 30, 30
  orig: 30, 30
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

so if your button size is 30, 30
then if you want your button to be slightly larger on the x axis, then make your orig 20, 30

Hope you like this  answer

If you need more help visit
[here](http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx) or find yourself more examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a padiding from the code inside a table.

this is an example from the wiki table:

**Padding**

*Padding is extra space around the edges of a cell.*

```
table.add(nameLabel);
table.add(nameText).width(100).padBottom(10); // Sets bottom padding.
table.row();
table.add(addressLabel);
table.add(addressText).width(100).pad(10);    // Sets top, left, bottom, right padding.
```

look this:

1. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table
2. https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout